# get thumbnail of an image in box.net

Tags: thumbnails, box-api

get_account_tree() API returns thumnail information. however, box.net published v2.0 APIs and no API does provide thumbnail information. This is important to quickly view image instead of downloading the entire image. Basically, I am looking for an API similar to the /thumbnail provided by dropbox. It will be extremely useful.

thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

Box supports thumbnails for images.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/thumbnail.png
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Documentation here:
http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get-a-thumbnail-for-a-file

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback.  The V2.0 API is still in beta, and we do plan to enhance some of the endpoints to include URLs for thumbnails.  Stay tuned for blog posts on http://developers.blog.box.com/ for updates to the V2 API.

Comment: thanks for quick update. I am still learning about /events. Let's see how it works out as enhancement to endpoints. I think having a separate API to retrieve thumbnail could be an easy implementation for application. Maybe, it's easier to get url straight from file object. other option could be to have a parameter for GET /files/{file id}/data. these are some random thoughts. I will keep checking the blog posts. thanks again!